# Could other people steal my Internet connection if they had my PPPoE data?

Tags: encryption, authentication, network, internet

Would it be possible for other people to use my PPPoE data to get Internet access or is it somehow restricted to my house? Then what about my neighbors downstairs, could they do it?
And what about intercepting a PPPoE login? Are PPPoE logins secured by encryption? If so, what encryption is used?

Comment: The PPPoE data can be used with any router/modem. However it will only work if the internet service is activated on the telephone line. Also the ISP should be same I guess. A vodafone PPPoE credentials might not work for some other ISP. Your neighbors can only use the PPPoE credentials if they connect to your telephone line. I once tried to give my modem to my friend with all credentials, but it didn't work, because no internet service was activated on his telephone line! Thats why a technician comes from ISP to configure the internet connection when you have a new connection.

Comment: For sniffing this could help: http://www.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/securityfocus/pen-test/2007-01/msg00128.html

Comment: So assuming my neighbors would have their own DSL etc and they would be using the same ISP as me, would he then be able to use my PPPoE data instead of theirs to get Internet access?

Comment: This I can't assure, because I never tested it. It may or may not work. The reason why it may NOT work is, your neighbour have their own DSL credentials which are different from yours. Now if they use your credentials to connect on their DSL line it will most probably not work because the ISP will see that this credentials are not issued for this(your neighbour's) DSL line. This is just a guess. I hope someone can provide some better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually tried this with my neighbor who is connected to same ISP.
PPPoE required 3 things:

- Username
- Password
- MAC if Binding is enabled by your ISP

I was able to get these things from my neighbor.
I spoofed the MAC address, started PPPoE connection with his credentials.
And BOOM I was able to use his IP.
But before that the PPPoE session of my neighbor has to be shut down.
There could be only one PPPoE session at a particular time.